# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 vs 1.0 if you don't need the extra features?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm reading about Identity 2.0, and all it seems to bring is extra stuff like 2 factor logins, Facebook logins, and other nice looking features.

However, I'm working on a project that only needs a simple username/password combination to log in, with password forgotten functionality, and that's it.

Is there any reason to use Identity 2.0 for something as simple as I'm planning? Is it more secure than 1.0 if I only need to implement the above mentioned features?

Comment: If you don't need it then don't use it. Not sure why you'd want an older version simply because you might not use the features of the new version.

Comment: @Shoe: The question is really why would you want a newer version if the older version works fine? I don't know how it applies to Identity, but older software is more likely to be debugged, may have a simpler API, and could be smaller (fewer dependencies, etc.).

Comment: @Gabe that is not the case here. If you start a greenfield project, there is no point in getting v1.0. Newer version is much better in this sense.

Comment: @Gabe I agree with you but as I read the question the only reason I see is because they don't need the extra features.